# Como receber nome de usuario do facebook? Graph API

Tags: facebook, node.js, api

Oi, pessoal. Como obter o id de um usuario do facebook, e seu nome usando Graph api?

Eu apenas consigo pegar o id das mensagens, usando `sender = event.sender.id;`

```
function fbGetProfile(id) {
   request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/${id}',
      qs: {
        fields: 'first_name',
        access_token:PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
      },
      json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
    } else if (response.body.error) {
      console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

O Graph API [já não permite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062011/facebook-graph-api-2-1-get-userid-from-username) procurar pelo username. Também acabo de conferir a documentação e não tem nada lá à respeito.

Vi que o HTML do Facebook contém duas meta tags com o User_ID:

```html
<!-- Na URL https://www.facebook.com/zuck -->
<meta property="al:android:url" content="fb://profile/4" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="fb://profile/4" />
```

[image: facebook graph api explorer]